# Where to put dummy web service implementations?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, testing

In a current project I have the following architecture:

- Internal-Proj
- ^ Internal-Proj-Impl
- External-Proj
- ^ External-Proj-Impl

The Internal project defines a web service (the interface is in Internal-Proj and the implementation in Impl, obviously). The external project consumes this web service. As such, there's a dependency from External-Proj-Impl to Internal-Proj.

We created a WebServiceDummy class which implements WebService, and will be used for tests in the External-Proj-Impl. The question is where should this WebServiceDummy be put ?

- In External-Proj-Impl: this doesn't create a new dependency. Downside: if a new project also needs a dummy, it will have to create its own. Also I like the idea that Internal is responsible for providing the dummies for their interfaces, and this won't be the case here.
- In Internal-Proj: this requires no new dependency, but it means having an implementation (albeit a dummy one) in the interface project.
- In Internal-Proj-Impl: this makes sense because the dummy is an implementation and not an interface. However this would mean that External-Proj-Impl now has a dependency on Internal-Proj-Impl, which is unacceptable.

In case that matters, we're using Spring, which means that we declare in the context whether we use a real implementation, a dummy or a webservice client, which is then injected.

Is there a best practice for this ?

Comment: Put it with the tests where it is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd put it together with the tests that use it, so:

> In External-Proj-Impl: this doesn't create a new dependency. Downside: if a new project also needs a dummy, it will have to create its own.

About the downside, not necessarily. You can have other projects make use of the "tests artefact" (in Maven terms). If those projects are completely unrelated, you could start a new "test support" project ("Internal-Proj-Testing", that only depends on Internal-Proj).